# Django 3: is_valid() is always false using FileField and FloatField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a simple form in Django that accepts some file upload fields and a few float fields. However, when I run this in my browser, the is_valid() never gets triggered even when all forms are filled in. I have looked through the Django docs and have tried to recreate the examples as much as possible, but I can't figure out what is wrong. I know that the is_valid() is not true because the page does not redirect to another page when submit is pressed. Also, if I go into the admin page, no instances of MyModel are made.

Here is my code.
models.py:

```
from django.db import models    

# Create your models here.
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file1 = models.FileField()
    file2 = models.FileField()
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    z = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file1
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import MyModel

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import MyForm

# Create your views here.
def index_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_page')
    else:
        form = DocumentsForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Home Page!</h1>

<form method="POST" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are sending both data and files, you need to specify the encoding of the form to:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is it has to do with the fact that you haven't included `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` declaration in the HTML.  It should look like this:

`<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="">`

The `multipart/form-data` is necessary when uploading a file through forms.